# Synaptics stole Alt+Shft+L -- how can I reclaim it?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, synaptics-touchpad

When I updated to Windows 10 it installed the latest Synaptics touchpad driver on my Lenovo W520. I tried to remove the driver but Windows brought it back with the next round of updates.

This particular driver registers a global keyboard hook on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to generate and show its log file. However, as long time user of Resharper, I was already using that keyboard shortcut regularly while running Visual Studio.

I don’t want to see the Synaptics log file, ever. I don’t even use the touchpad. I tried disabling it in the “Device Manager.” Does anyone know how to kill the Synaptics global keyboard hook?

Comment: See this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023451/eclipse-altshiftl-conflict-with-window-shortcut

Comment: Thanks for the link. This does appear to be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/touchpad-driver-diagnostic-pop-up/f8ad5ca2-9559-4327-9b7e-bdaaaca4d2b1?auth=1):

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SynTP\Parameters\Debug /v DumpKernel /d 00000000 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Then reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. I tried with uninstallation of synaptics driver uninstall completely
2. then restarted my device
3. installed driver taken from official website of my laptop.

woww... issue gone .